# Android studio - Support repository installation error

Tags: android-studio

Latest version of Android studio got installed.
On creating a new project, Android Support Repository installation starts,
Download completes, during unzip, throws an error like installation failed.
How to resolve, latest version of java, react native is installed.

Error Output:

To install:
- Android Support Repository (extras;android;m2repository)

Installing Android Support Repository
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r35.zip
Installing Android Support Repository in C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository
An error occurred during installation: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\databinding\adapters\1.0-rc0\adapters-1.0-rc0-javadoc.jar (The system cannot find the path specified).
Failed to install Android Support Repository!

Failed packages:
- Android Support Repository (extras;android;m2repository)

Answer (score 1):

Th solution for this is :

```
1.Run Android Studio as Administrator
2.Re run the update
```

It will work.